# Coercing a KVC type

Tags: cocoa, ios, macos, cocoa-bindings

I would like to parse XML to populate KVC compliant objects but, my parser is very dumb, it simply assembles NSStrings from the XML attributes/tags and tries to set them via KVC.

This works for actual strings and numbers (I believe) but I need to also set dates. The problem is obviously that the parser doesn't know the string represents a date and it tries to sit it using the vanilla KVC calls - afterwhich the KVC framework complains about the type mismatch (setting a string on a date field).

Is there a programmatic way to 'intercept' invocations into the KVC framework such that I can alter the data being set (run a date string through an NSDateFormatter)?

I could put some intelligence into the parser but before doing so, are there any other well-known solutions for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the perfect solution, but... I'd like to share my ideas ;)

So, first of all, take a look here: [Key-Value Coding - Validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173). That document describes a neat way to validate your variable the moment it's set via KVC. You could use this to your advantage by:

1. First implement KV Validation method for your class variable
2. Set your value
3. In your validation method check if it's a date/string/whatever you wish - and change it to proper type.

This should provide a clean implementation for ensuring proper type.

Cheers,
Pawel

Comment: +1 I think I may actually prefer using validation to my answer. It would certainly keep the code tidier if there are several attributes that need coercing.

Comment: I saw this functionality ... but didn't catch that I could actually replace the object. Nice call. It also seems that this is implemented at the field level, ie: no field name comparison/lookup (validate<Key>:error:) Would I need to manage the memory of the object I was replacing? I bet I'd need to autorelease the new NSDate ... especially if it were being set on a (nonatomic,retain) property. The only other issue is that some set's on this field might not need to be converted to dates (they already are). I'll try and mock up a perf test. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With KVC, everything goes through a default implementation of `setValue:forKey:` whichs calls the appropriate mutator method ([as described here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955)).

You can just override `setValue:forKey:` to check for the key or keys that need transforming, and make appropriate changes.

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if([key isEqualToString:@"someDate"]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        someDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];
        value = somedate;
    }

    [super setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

That's from memory, so no guarantees whether it'll actually compile and run. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Paul. This is definitely a possibility. From a performance standpoint, I may need to quantify the performance penalty of the string comparison. The other problem is that ... sometimes, other parts of the program may attempt to set a real NSDate on this field ... in which case I'd have to check for the class type as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If there's a chance that the correct type might be passed in, then I'd suggest Pawel's answer. I'd have thought the string comparison performed well enough, particularly in the context of parsing XML.